# Image recognation problem to create dataset

Tags: python, dataset

The folders train and test contain one sub-folder per class of image, with the name of the sub-folder corresponding to the name of the class. In our case we only have 2 classes: insect and flower (meaning, without any insect). The function `create_dataset()` is provided to you (below) and creates a labelled dataset from a folder `img_folder`.

```py
np.random.seed(1)

def create_dataset(img_folder, img_size=(224, 224)):
    
    images = []
    class_names = []
    image_names = []
    image_hashes = []

    for class_dir in os.listdir(img_folder):
        for img_name in os.listdir(os.path.join(img_folder, class_dir)):
            image_path = os.path.join(img_folder, class_dir,  img_name)
            image = cv2.imread(image_path) # BGR format
            image_hash = str(hash(image.tobytes()))
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # RGB format
            image = cv2.resize(image, img_size,interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            images.append(image)
            class_names.append(class_dir)
            image_names.append(img_name)
            image_hashes.append(image_hash)
        
    images = np.asarray(images)
    class_names = np.asarray(class_names)
    image_names = np.asarray(image_names)
    image_hashes = np.asarray(image_hashes)

    perm = np.random.permutation(len(images))

    return images[perm], class_names[perm], image_names[perm], image_hashes[perm]
```

I have to create the training for the test data set. I have created the code but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

```
test_dir = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/your_project/data/test'
train_dir = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/your_project/data/train'

img_data_train, class_names_train, image_names_train, image_hashes_train = create_dataset(train_dir)
img_data_test, class_names_test, image_names_test, image_hashes_test = create_dataset(test_dir)
```